# Zend Db Statement - reset loop

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework 1.12.2 and build a query:

```
$sitesSql = 'SELECT * FROM app_sites';
$stmtSites = $db->query($sitesSql);
```

And I want to loop throw the rows twice.

```
while ($row = $stmtSites->fetch()) {
[...]
}
```

dozens of lines below

```
while ($row = $stmtSites->fetch()) {
[...]
}
```

But unfortunately the second loop doesnt loop from the beginning.
So just above the second while I must reset the statement - how? Like [mysqli_data_seek()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

Comment: What do you really want to do? As you don't necessarily have to loop through twice (EDIT: if you do nothing "physically" to the records you could also embed the two loops, perhaps?)

Comment: I making several thinks in both loops. This script is some script which fill database with random datas in many of scenarios. So I can't merge the loops :(

Comment: in this case give out the "$stmtSites = $db->query($sitesSql);" command again... and fetch...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use `fetchAll()` (which returns an array) instead?

```
$sites = $db->fetchAll($sitesSql);
```

then you can just loop through the results with foreach twice:

```
foreach ($sites as ...) {

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use fetchAll() method because the app_sites have hundreds of thousands records and the memory wont be enought to keep all the table data.